# How can i evaluate an expectation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I've a problem with function dblquad when i want to evaluate an expectation of normal distribution vector.
Here is a code:

```
p2 = @(X)(mvnpdf(X,zeros(4,1),sigma2));
int1 = dblquad(@(x, y)(p2([x; y; Y1])), 0,1,0,1)
```

where Y1 is [a;b] - constant vector. And it arises such an error:

```
??? Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

Help, please, if someone knows how to correct this.

Comment: if one needs all the code, i'll add it

Comment: Your `p2` function has an array of 4 elements as output; Do you want to integrate them all independently?

Answer (score 0):

The integrand should be able to accept vectorial input. It now is

```
@(x, y)(p2([x; y; Y1]))
```

which will error if x or y or vectors. hence the `??? Error using ==> vertcat`.

This can be fixed by using arrayfun:

```
@(x, y) arrayfun(@(yi) arrayfun(@(xi) p2([xi; yi; Y1]), x), y)
```

But this doesn't solve another problem: the integrand has vector output, even when inputs `x` and `y` are scalar.

It actually makes no sense to me why you are trying to doubly integrate that function. It look like the elements in the variable X in `p2` each have an independend output...